How to divide one page into two columns in quarto rendering to typst
As the title says, I am trying to divide one page into two columns of a quarto document that is being rendered to pdf using typst.
I have tried these two options
Option 1: pandoc columns

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="60%"}
blablablablablabla
:::

:::{.column width="40%"}
blablablabla
:::

::::


Option 2: raw typst

# Here's the title
```{typst}
#set page(columns: 2) ```




blablablablablabla

```{typst}
#colbreak() ```

blablablabla



In both cases, the resulting typst code was
= Here's the title
<heres-the-title>
blablablablablabla

blablablabla

And hence, no columns.

You can do this within the typst-template.typ file by adding show: columns.with(2). There are some additional configuration options you can include. See example templates here (lines 177-179) and here (lines 142-144).
With this solution you can't explicitly specify what text appears in each column - it just fills the first column and then continues into the next column (similar to how it would work in MS Word).
I used the quarto create extension format command referenced here which set up the _extensions directory for typst. That created two .typ files: typst-show.typ and typst-template.typ.
Here is the typst-template.typ:
#let report(
  title: "title",
  body,
) = {
// adjust page defaults here 
set page(
  "us-letter",
  margin: (
  left: 1in, 
  right: 1in, 
  top: 1in, 
  bottom: 1in
  ))
    
  // Start two column mode and configure paragraph properties.
  show: columns.with(2)
  
  // Display the paper's contents.
  body
  
}

Here is the typst-show.typ:
#show: body => report(
$if(title)$
  title: [$title$],
$endif$

$if(by-author)$
  authors: (
$for(by-author)$
$if(it.name.literal)$
    ( name: [$it.name.literal$]),
$endif$
$endfor$),
$endif$

$if(date)$
  date: [$date$],
$endif$
  body,
)

